# How to run the pyspark shell code as a job like we run Python jobs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am very new to spark.

I have created the spark code in pyspark but it is repl shell, how can I run this as a script.

I tried `python script.py` but it fails as it cannot access spark libraries.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/sql-getting-started.html should help.

Answer (score 0):

`spark-submit script.py` is the way to submit a pyspark code.

Before using this please make sure pyspark and spark is properly set up in your environment.

If not done yet, do follow the below [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-apache-pyspark-on-windows-10-f5f0c506bea1)